# Unable to create a bootable USB drive using Linux Mint

Tags: live-usb

I'm trying to use a 64-bit Linux Mint machine to make a bootable Windows USB drive, but it's not working correctly, so I think there's a problem with the imaging process.

I downloaded the 32-bit ISO of Windows 10 from [Microsoft's website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). Then I opened USB Image Writer (which comes with Linux Mint; I used the GUI), set the image to the ISO I obtained, and the destination to `/dev/sdb`, which is the location of the USB drive I inserted.

However, despite setting the machine's boot settings to Legacy with Secure Boot off, and even moving the USB to the top of the boot order list, it does not boot. I am on a Dell Inspiron 15 laptop, and I was using a Sandisk 128GB flash drive as a USB.

---

As requested in the comments:

```
$ sudo file /dev/sdb
block special
```

Comment: This question is not necessarily off-topic (@roaima) since you're using Linux to set up the USB stick and that might be where the problem is. However, we would need a lot more information to help you. How **exactly** did you use USB image writer? Describe it so that someone reading your description can obtain the same content by following your instructions. What is the output of `sudo file -s /dev/sdb`? What happens when you try to boot — what output on the screen?

Comment: @roaima [USB ImageWriter](https://launchpad.net/usb-imagewriter) looks like a Linux program.

Comment: @Gilles - oh ok. I'll go with "Unclear" then, and if the question gets updated I'll happily vote/concur to reopen.

Comment: @roaima How is this unclear? This is just wasting my time...

Comment: @Yoshimaster it's unclear because we don't (yet) have any clear idea of the process you used to get to your situation. Please update your question to include responses to Gilles' questions in the first comment (and please note that your `file /dev/sdb` isn't what Gilles asked). PC hardware (make, model) is often necessary for "won't boot" issues.

Comment: @roaima Hopefully this is clarified properly.

Comment: @Gilles Hopefully this is clarified properly.

Comment: Clarification: Did OP manage to solve this question since then? I will upvote if OP can [self-answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) with working solution on Linux.